# How should I initialize a string variable that gets assigned later?

Tags: typescript, variables

In TypeScript, if I have a variable called `endpoint` and it is later assigned by an API call. Should I initialize the `endpoint` to be `null` , `undefined` or an empty string `''`?

Comment: by default the value is `undefined` so no point assigning the same value.
between `null` and `''` i prefer empty string.

Comment: @Navneetkumar I know by default it is `undefined`. but still I need to explicitly give it a value when initialzing it. So you think `undefined` is a better option than `null`?

Comment: I prefer empty string `''`

Answer (score 0):

A variable can be declared without an explicit initial value like this:

```
let foo: string | undefined; // undefined
// ...
foo = api.get("something"); // Now assigned
```

Comment: better to do `let foo = ''` that way you are precisely telling typescript compiler to infer `String` which can be mutated in future (with only strings)

Comment: How is that more precise than explicitly declaring the type?

Comment: `string | undefined` means it can be either string or undefined.

Comment: Correct, which is arguably more precise for the case that the assignment fails. If the assignment were guaranteed, I'm not sure why one would separate the declaration and assignment.

Comment: Agreed Arguably, now `undefined` is a parent of all datatype (in Js) hence you lost precision there itself. Now reason for separate declaration and assignment could be a wider scope.